# Populating a table for a row x column design using vba in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, populate

I am new in creating VBA in excel. Therefore I am struggling with the basics. I would like to create a VBA to populate a table related to row by column statistical design. For instance, if want to generate a table for a row by column design with 2 rows and 3 columns my table would look like this:

[image: 2 x 3 table]

or if I want to use the VBA to create a table for a 3 by 2 row by column design the table would look like this:

[image: 3 x 2 table]

and so forth

Could someone help me develop a simple VBA where I can choose the number of rows and columns for my layout and then use the VBA to generate the respective tables?

Comment: Would you mind sharing what code you had tried.. ? ( :

Comment: Dear friend. I haven´t tried anything I have no idea how to start this.

Comment: How about start by creating a macro where you simulate a table creation? Then view the code to get you started...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the code:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim a() As Long
    Dim i As Long

    x = 2 ' columns
    y = 3 ' rows
    ReDim a(1 To x * y, 1 To 2)
    For i = 0 To x * y - 1
        a(i + 1, 1) = i Mod y + 1
        a(i + 1, 2) = i \ y + 1
    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(x * y, 2).Value = a

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I made some changes to your original code. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @Carvalho IMO good idea to edit the question and post the code with changes you made, it can help others.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over rows and columns to create a table.

Here's what I mean:

```
Dim row As Long
Dim column As Long
Dim end_row As Long
Dim end_col As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Dim index As Long

Set wb = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheet("worksheet name")

'alternatively, you can do this too if you prefer to use numbers
'Set ws = wb.Worksheet(index)

end_row = 3
end_col = 2

'this loop iterates over rows
For row = 1 To end_row
    'this loop iterates over columns
    For column = 1 To end_col
        'sets headers
        If row = 1 Then
            ws.Cells(row, 1).Value = "Column 1"
            ws.Cells(row, 2).Value = "Column 2"
        'puts row numbers in column 1
        ElseIf row > 1 Then
            ws.Cells(row, 1).Value = row
        End If 
            'puts column numbers in row 2
            ws.Cells(2, column).Value = column
    Next
Next
```

Hope this helps!